# I want to have a function that returns true, when I compare a null String and an Empty String

Tags: java

I need to compare an empty("") String and a Null String and return true.

```
String a = "";
String b = null;

// return TRUE if I compare "" and null
return TRUE if I compare null and null
return TRUE if I compare "" and ""

return false if a or b has some value
```

Comment: This is trivially easy to do, what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: and `""` compared to `""` should not also return `true` ? Same thing for `null` and `null`. Your requirement is unclear.

Comment: @JonK I tried .equals and ==, didn't get true in any case.

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work.

Comment: @davidxxx "" compared to "" should give true, null compared to null should give true, "" compared to null should also give true

Comment: So in the end you want both variables to be null or empty. There is no comparison necessary

Comment: @JonK - I may have been. Comment deleted :)

Comment: Why not just `return a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @Zephyr Because that would throw a `NullPointerException` if `a` or `b` was `null`

Comment: What about null and ""? Is it also true?

Comment: @rw026 Yes, I should get true on comparing null and "" , That's my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function to not repeat yourself :

```
String a = ...;
String b = ...;

Predicate<String> isNullOrEmpty = s -> s == null || s.equals("");
return isNullOrEmpty.test(a) && isNullOrEmpty.test(b);
```

You can also rely on Apache Command Lang that provides `StringUtils.isEmpty()` :

```
return StringUtils.isEmpty(a) && StringUtils.isEmpty(b);
```

Comment: What if a or b has some value ?

Comment: It returns false.  You could write an unit test and you could check all of that

Answer (score 0):

Your actual usecase is not to compare the strings to each other but instead you want to check if one of both is not empty.

The following snippet should do the job:

```
public boolean func(String a, String b) {
    if (a != null && !a.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (b != null && !b.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```